# Finding tight lower limit for time complexity of any algorithmic puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is a question in my Job Interview.
How do you find common elements in two arrays?How can you prove time complexity of this solution is optimum,i.e one can't further reduce the time complexity of this problem?
I gave a nlogn+(n+m) alogithm solution for this problem.n,m are sizes of given arrays,n>m.I was unable to answer second part of question.Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comparisons-only model, sorting is essentially required. Consider an adversary that chooses inputs where, in the sorted order over both arrays, the elements alternate between input arrays. For each element, the algorithm has to "prove" that it is less than some of the other array's elements and greater than all of the others. Because of the strict interleaving, this information adds up to a total order on all the elements, which yields an Omega(n log n) lower bound.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Actually David gives a rather convincing sketch for proving an information theoretic lower bound in the [decision tree model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_model) if no further assumptions are made. It can probably be generalized to the randomized decision tree model as well. Using hash functions doesn't really help if you are analyzing in the worst case

Comment: @NiklasB. He changed the answer a bit, and I had a second comment that got blocked when this answer was briefly deleted

Comment: @David Thanks for answer.So I know that sorting can't be done with lesser time complexity than O(n log n) i.e by decision tree method.In general to find the lower limit for some other problems like MST,Shortest path or any other problem,how should I approach.

Comment: @nagallapruthvi The decision tree complexity of MST is a notorious open problem. I don't know about shortest path. In general, trying to figure out why the algorithm has to sort is much more of an art than a science.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in time complexity `n + m` You can create a `HashSet` which is complexity of time `n`, then do a contains for every element in the other array.  That is of time complexity `(O(1)*m)=m`.  For a total of `n+m`.

You can prove this by contradiction.  As in, you suppose the opposite of what you think is true, then logically prove that it must be impossible, therefore your supposition is wrong.  If you choose your supposition correctly, then negation of it will prove your original point.

**Supposition:** Suppose there was an algorithm with time complexity lower than `m+n` that finds all common elements in two arrays.

This implies there is at least one element that you didn't inspect.  That element could be common or not.  You can't know without inspecting it.  So this algorithm doesn't guarantee you find all common elements, which is a contradicting of the original **Supposition**.  Therefore, there is no algorithm with a smaller complexity than `n+m` for finding common elements.

Comment: Hashing is not actually an O(m + n)-time algorithm though (expected, yes).

Comment: I'm making the assumption that you can create a good enough hashing function.

Comment: @carlos But we can't find such hash function in real life.Can we?Is there any method to find one?

Comment: Given a specific situation, you (probably) are  able to construct a hash function that is able to disperse the elements you are trying to look through.  To contrast this with the other answer, the problem of having to sort elements, that is, to have to construct a Total ordering of all the elements. can be more difficult than creating proper hash function.  Honestly I think creating a hash is easier, because you can just throw and md5 hash at it and be done.  Imposing a total ordering on elements though, can be a more involved problem.

Comment: @carlos Can you give any hash function for my problem.I am unable to find one.Anyway using a hash function given the type of input looks more feasible and productive approach.But here the input is unbounded.

Comment: Objects have to make their own hash function, usually it will use different members of the object to create it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()